# Xpath query for processing XML

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to process following xml Using xpath query

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UDSObjectList>
  <UDSObject>
    <Handle>chg:400106</Handle>
    <Attributes>
      <Attribute DataType="2002">
        <AttrName>chg_ref_num</AttrName>
        <AttrValue>123</AttrValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute DataType="2002">
        <AttrName>requestor.combo_name</AttrName>
        <AttrValue>ServiceDesk, Administrator </AttrValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute DataType="2005">
        <AttrName>status</AttrName>
        <AttrValue>AA</AttrValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute DataType="2005">
        <AttrName>priority</AttrName>
        <AttrValue>3</AttrValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute DataType="2002">
        <AttrName>log_agent.combo_name</AttrName>
        <AttrValue>ServiceDesk, Administrator </AttrValue>
      </Attribute>
      <Attribute DataType="2002">
        <AttrName>assignee.combo_name</AttrName>
        <AttrValue>Smith</AttrValue>
      </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
  </UDSObject>
</UDSObjectList>
```

I want to get the AttrValue of AttrName='chg_ref_num' using xpath query what will be the exact query.

I am trying using

```
"//UDSObject/Attributes/Attribute/AttrValue[AttrName=chg_ref_num]/text()"
```

but not getting the AttrValue.

Comment: try this `"//UDSObject/Attributes/Attribute/AttrValue[AttrName='chg_ref_num']/text()"`

Answer (score 0):

```
"/UDSObjectList/UDSObject/Attributes/Attribute/AttrName[text()="chg_ref_num"]/parent::*/AttrValue/text()"
```

Comment: You can also make it:
/Attribute[(AttrName[text()="chg_ref_num"])]/AttrValue/text()

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the parent node to get the correct element. So with the following xPath you are searching an Attribute element which has a child who's text node has the searched value. From that Attribute element, you access the AttrValue node's text node.

Like this here:

```
//UDSObject/Attributes/Attribute[./AttrName/text()='chg_ref_num']/AttrValue/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `following-sibling` axis

```
//AttrName[.='chg_ref_num']/following-sibling::AttrValue/text()
```

Demo - http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/c50bed92-850e-41b9-9a01-a5ecea6ead3e